# Partial covariance matrix after linear transformations

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, partial-least-squares, partial-correlation

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_m)$ be two multivariate random variables.

We denote with $\Sigma(X)$ the $n\times n$ covariance matrix $\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$ and with $\Sigma(X,Y)$ the $n\times m$ cross covariance matrix $\text{cov}(X_i,Y_\alpha)$.

The partial covariance  $\Sigma(X|Y)$ is defined as
$$\Sigma(X|Y) = \Sigma(X) - \Sigma(X,Y)\Sigma(Y)^{-1}\Sigma(X,Y)^{\intercal}.$$

If $T$ and $U$ are respective
matrices for linear transformations on $X$ and $Y$, could someone explain why the following holds?

$$\Sigma(TX|UY) = T\,\Sigma(X|Y)\,T^{\intercal}$$

**What I did**

I have shown that
\begin{align}
\Sigma(TX) &=\mathbb{E}[(X-T\overline{X})(TX-T\overline{X})^{\intercal}] \\
           &= \mathbb{E}[T(X-\overline{X})(X-\overline{X})^{\intercal}T^{\intercal}] \\
           &= T\mathbb{E}[(X-\overline{X})(X-\overline{X})^{\intercal}]T^{\intercal} \\
           &= T \Sigma(X) T^{\intercal}
\end{align}
and in a similar fashion that
$$\Sigma(TX,UY) = T\Sigma(X,Y)U^{\intercal} $$

Comment: This is easy to prove if you assume that $U$ is an invertible (square matrix) since then you have $(U\Sigma_{yy}U^T)^{-1}=U^{-T}\Sigma_{yy}^{-1}U^{-1}$ but in general I don't think it is true.  After all, it would be strange if conditioning all the components of $y$ would have the same effect as conditioning on say, only $y_1+y_2$ (the case of $U=[1,1]$) (intuitively, the conditional variance should be larger for the latter form of conditioning).

Comment: Thanks @JarleTufto , I was close.  I agree that $U$ should be non-singular... I suppose the intuition here is that otherwise you are removing some information from the regression model... on the other hand, when $U$ is a "normal" matrix you are using linear combinations of the vector components $Y$ and then you are not adding any extra information, so in the special case that $T=\mathbb{I}$ we have that $\Sigma(X|UY)=\Sigma(X|Y)$ does not change... do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, if $U$ is invertible, then if you know $UY$, then you also know $Y$ so conditioning on either vector is the same thing.